# How can I search and replace for two characters with a string in between and only replace the latter character using sed?

Tags: sed

Take the following string, for example:

```
some random text*
- sed is actually not that easy.*
other text
```

How can I search for lines containing both `-` and `*`, then replace the asterisk in that line with a string?

(For Example) Using the string "test" to replace the asterik in matched lines, the output would look this:

```
some random text*
- sed is actually not that easy.test
other text
```

I tried

```
sed -i '' 's/\- .*\*/\n\n:::\n/g';
```

But the problem with that is that it replaces the whole line, instead of just the asterisk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match and keep the hyphen at the start of the line, and replace the asterix at the end of the line, you can use a capture group `\(...\)` for what you want to keep and use that group in the replacement with `\1`

```
sed -i 's/^\(- .*\)\*$/\1test/' file
```

The contents of `file` will be:

```
some random text*
- sed is actually not that easy.test
other text
```

If the characters are not directly at the start or end of the string, you can remove the anchors `^` and `$`